# Installation service in installshield

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installation, installshield, installshield-2010

The question is simple ... But at the same time, I don `t know how to do it. On the internet I found nothing. How to install service in installshield?

2010 (16) Premier Edition SP1 | basic msi project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InstallShield does have a wizard that helps you configure Windows NT services. Here are some basic instructions to get you started.

1. In the View Lists under Organization, click Components.
2. Right-click the Components node and then click Component Wizard. The Component Wizard opens.
3. On the Welcome panel of the wizard, select the second option, which lets you install and control Windows NT services.
4. The next panel has options such as Install NT Service and Control NT Service. Select the Control NT Service option to delete the service at run time. (Then, later you can create a separate component by re-runnning the wizard and selecting the Install NT Service option, which will let you update the service on the target machine and specify when it should be started.)
5. Complete the wizard.

InstallShield creates a new component for the service that you are installing or controlling. To revise any of the service's settings, expand the Advanced Settings node for that component, and then click the Control NT Services node or the Install NT Services node. Modify any settings that are displayed on the right as appropriate.

Note: These instructions apply to the Premier and Professional editions of InstallShield, but not the Express edition.

Comment: @alexeyivanov thanks for the edit, i am still trying to get good at the Stack Exchange formatting!